# Dojo Widget - Silent fail between BuildRendering and PostCreate

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, recursion, dojo, widget

I'm trying to develop a table of content style widget for a map in my web application. The widgets works quite well in Chrome and FireFox but fails silently in internet explorer 8  (I have read that so many times while developping this application!)

I'm using the dojo framework and I figured out that it fails between the BuildRendering and PostCreate methods of the widget lifecycle. The widget is created using a graph structure so it is recursive. Does anyone have any idea what can cause failure between these two methods of the widget life cycle?

I have read in some places that the template may be a problem, so I've included it following my Node code.

Here's a simplified version of the widget so you can maybe get an idea of what's happening :

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", 
        "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin", "dojo/text!./templates/_Node.html"], 

function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template) {

    var _Node = declare ([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], { 

        templateString : template,
        _childNodes : [],

        constructor : function (params, srcNodeRef) {
            lang.mixin(this, params);   
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        buildRendering: function (){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            // Execution leaves this function but never launches postCreate()
            // buildRendering is not actually there in my code, I just have it here for 
            // debugging this particular problem.
        },

        postCreate : function () { 
            // Execution never reaches this point in IE8 (probably 7 and 9 as well)
            var newParams = {
                "Para1": "Value1",
                "Para2": "Value2"
            }
            var newNode = new Node(newParams, this.containerNode);
            this._childNodes.push(newNode);
        }
    });

    return _Node;

});
```

And here's the template it uses:

```
<div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="rowNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick">
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="contentNode">
            <span data-dojo-attach-point="checkContainerNode"></span>
            <img src="${_blankGif}" alt="" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode">
            <span data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

So my node follows this structure but like I said, silently fails between buildRendering and postCreate in Internet Explorer. I've spent quite a bit of time on this already. I hope someone can give me a hand here.

And please don't look at the syntax too much, I copy pasted parts of my code but I modified it heavily for clarity.

Thanks,

Ggilmann

Comment: I can't say that my answer will solve your problem, but I just listed a few things that I noticed when reviewing your code.

Comment: I've copied your code and ran it in both Firefox and IE8, it seems to work perfectly in both.  Have tried running in IE7 mode, quirks mode, compatibility mode, ...etc, all work. I'm guessing what is breaking this is something not included in the modified version above.  My bet would be on that something in the template is breaking it as this is being fetched and included during buildRendering.  Have tried to break it by not including an _onClick() class method or _blankGif property but these have no specifically destructive in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to call `this.inherited(arguments);` in the constructor.  Dojo will automatically chain constructors.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/declare.html#id8

You also need to add `this.inherited(arguments);` to `postCreate`.

Your template does not have a closing tag for `<img>`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll retry all this again tommorrow. I say retry because I have, unfortunately already tried all your suggestions. The closing img I read somewhere that it was not required so I tried with or without. The inherited calls I initially tried without and added them as pretty much the last thing i tried.  The inherited in the postCreate, though it might be required, would not be called since it never enters postcreate. A bit pessimist but I will try it all again tommorrow.

Comment: Closing img in HTML5 is not needed (assuming HTML5, if XHTML then it ought to be included).  Also, I never use this.inherited(arguments) at all (if possible) as it will not work when using "use strict".  Your class ought to work without any of these (most of the time, there are exceptions of course).  The lang.mixin(this, params) in the constructor should not be needed as Dojo should do this.  I'd ditch the constructor method (unless of course, you are running more code there that you removed in order to make your question easier to understand).